# Calling REST service from Apps for Office task pane app

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, apps-for-office

I'm playing around with Apps for Office, an Excel TaskPane app.

I'm using AngularJS if that matters.

When I call my REST service build with WebApi I get access denied errors from the javascript.

I've read up on JSONP and CORS and enabled CORS in my REST service but to no help. I can't even see the request hitting my service or leaving Excel in fiddler.

In the app manifest I've tried to add my REST service to the allowed AppDomain's but this don't help either.

So is it possible to to call a cross domain REST service from an Apps For Office TaskPane app in Excel?

If so how?

Comment: You use HTTP or HTTPS? Try do disable SSL if you are using simple HTTP in the project config... - that worked for me...

Comment: I'm using simple HTTP atm., but will need to use HTTPS at a later stage since the data need to be secured.

Comment: With HTTPS it works without much configuration. With HTTP you have to explicitly disable SSL in your project config.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Did you solve the issue? If so can you post the answer.. We need to clean up this tag a bit. Thanks.